# What jre is required for an application written in java 1.7?

Tags: java, compatibility

I have a project for school written with jdk 1.7. This application will be distributed to other groups and we want to document the necessary user system requirements. I'm assuming that the user will need the jre corresponding to jdk 1.7. Is this correct? Or what is the best recommendation for the user? The latest jre version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JRE 1.7 + version will be good to use.

**On a side note:-**

It is nothing like that your Java 6 code will not run on Java 7 code. The difference is that  the speed increases when running them on later runtimes. This is because Java is constantly evolving, not just the language but also the JVM (Java virtual machine). SO it would be an added advantage of speed if you choose to use the later versions.

Answer (score 1):

Latest JRE version which will be 1.7+ is good.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you use the `-target` and/or the `-source` options to `javac`, you may be able to compile with a recent JDK and run with an older JRE.

Answer (score 0):

JRE 1.7 version.

If you want to target, let's say, a Java 6 VM, then you can do that with the Java 7 SDK tools. You can specify which target VM you wish to support, but you have to know that a version 6 VM might not support all the features a version 7 VM will.